# How to read GET and POST request in PHP (post is in json)

Tags: php, post, get

I have a javascript (not from me) to sync information between client (javascript) and server (php) and javascript send to server GET and POST information, I can read easy GET information so I try to read `$_POST` information and cannot retrieve POST information.

I try `print_r($_POST)` and just returns `Array()` with nothing.

I try to look it with Firebug and Console into Firefox and I see that

[image]

How can I retrieve and treat json string into >Transmission de la requete< into my PHP code? I can easily retrieve GET parameters such as token, src and etc so I can't retrieve POST transmission.

Thank you for your helping !

Comment: Is the request sent over post json

Comment: I think yes, so i'm not sure, i see under the GET parameters, the json string contain "channel", "ext", "fm.meta" "profileID" etc and i try to read this informations from request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really get you. But since it's something like JSON request sent to the page. You can use the `file_get_contents('php://input')` to grab any JSON request sent. Then you can decode it into an object or an array.

Example

```
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

**To obtain an object**

```
$input = json_decode($request);
```

So Input fields will be

```
$input->name; $input->password;
```

**To Obtain an array**

```
$input = json_decode($request, true);
```

So Input fields will be

```
$input[name]; $input[password];
```

Comment: Tank you is  this line: $request = file_get_contents('php://input'); can give me access to json string ! MANY THANK YOU !!!!